# Can we use org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint annotated class to create RESTful web service with Spring

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, soap

I have to create RESTful web service in an existing application which currently provides SOAP services and thus uses `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint`, so could I use `@Endpoint` annotated class instead of `@RestController` to create RESTful web service with Spring and can these classes have following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myMethod", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> restMethod() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: No... Those are for SOAP based endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@Endpoint* annotation mark a class as a **SOAP** endpoint, which will handle through its methods **SOAP** requests. Whereas *@RestController*, according to it javadoc, is "a convenience annotation that is itself annotated with *@Controller* and *@ResponseBody*", that is a very convenient mechanism to create **REST** services. So you can not use *@Endpoint* waiting for it to behave like *@RestController*.